# How to stop safari from autopopulating maps.apple.com over maps.google.com

Tags: macos, safari, maps

Safari 16.0
Macos 12.6

Sometime recently safari has started to autopopulate apple maps instead of google maps. I like most of you hate apple maps and want to continue using google maps.

[image: example]

How do I stop this from happening?  I *never* use apple maps so I feel like there was an update somewhere recently where apple is preferring their maps instead of their competitors.

Answer (score 1):

The result is based on habit; the system learning your usage patterns - so long as you don't keep deleting History & Cookies. Every time you sweep your usage patterns, or use aggressive blocking tactics, ad blockers or VPNs etc, then the algorithms have to start again.
A "Top Hit" is somewhere you have been before, it's not the same as a Siri suggestion. Which lands at the top of the list is a simple algorithm - the one you either have been to most, or most recently if there's not enough habitual data to make a decision.

If you use one more than the other, it will swing the other way in a short while. I only need to type `m` & Google maps is the autofill. I use Google Maps *a lot*; several times daily.

[image]

My partner has completely different usage patterns. She hardly, if ever looks at any map, so it's not 'habitual' at all. On her machine I have to type `map` before anything map-like is suggested at all. There is no suggested auto-fill or top hit because I doubt she has ever visited any map site, ever. Apple maps at that point isn't even in the suggestion list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can open history (<kbd>⌘+Y</kbd>) and search for `https://maps.apple.com` and delete all results. It should remove `maps.apple.com from your suggestions.

I would also note that `maps.google.com` is not the address for Google Maps,  it responds `302 MOVED` which might cause browsers to de-prioritize it as it doesn't have content.

Comment: `maps.google.com` redirects just fine for me, always has done, and is a whole lot easier to start typing in the top bar than `www.google.com/maps` which is where it redirects to.

Comment: Yeas, I understand it works fine but it redirects first which some browsers use to adjust their prioritization since it's no longer the real address